# Switch optimization for many cases guarantees equal access time for any case? ( C++ )

Tags: c++, c, optimization, switch-statement

I've seen answers here for specific languages, about switches with more than 5 cases being optimized with jump tables to guarantee constant access time for any case.
Is that so for C / C++?
Is it in particular for gcc? for visual studio?
If not, would sorting cases in order of occurrence frequency help?

Comment: Seems like it would make C a "Go killer" if they could optimize a switch statement rather well ...

Comment: I'd be *very* surprised if hashing was faster for 6 cases. Perhaps for 25. Sure, a hash table will probably reduce the variance in access time, but it does so by adding a fixed overhead.

Comment: I'm sure you understand that this only matters if the switch branches don't actually do much, and if the PC is actually in the switch a significant fraction of time, like 10% or more. Otherwise it's basically quantum noise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The standard doesn't guarantee anything about how the switch statement will be implemented. I've never seen a compiler produce a hash table, though quite a few will produce a jump table. Unless my memory is working even worse than usual, both VS and gcc can produce jump tables when the cases are sufficiently dense (for different values of "sufficiently"). Unfortunately, it's almost impossible to say (or necessarily even figure out) when sorting by frequency of occurrence will help -- it's different not only between compilers, but even between different versions of the same compiler.

Comment: @Pretruza: you could fix your original post

Comment: Because compiler implementors are lazy, and there was no need yet for big switch arrays. Unless unicode came along.
 
See the performance comparison here: https://programming.sirrida.de/hashsuper.pdf
perfect hashes are constant, jump tables only work for dense arrays, elsif chains are linear.

Answer (score 5):

For gcc's implementation see:

http://old.nabble.com/optimization-of-switch-statements-on-i386-to15366926.html#a15367662

Comment: The link is dead; is there another copy somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

- C and C++ guarantee nothing about the running time of switch statements.
- I'm afraid I don't know the implementation details for any compiler. It probably depends on optimisation flags.
- Sorting cases isn't guaranteed to help, again it's not specified by the standard, and your implementation may or may not:

  - Do different things according to compiler options
  - Document what it does
  - Guarantee not to change what it does in future versions
  - Completely ignore the order of cases in the source, and re-order them however it likes. Assuming of course the cases are "independent": no fall-through; no variable declarations starting in one case and spanning another case; no anything else I've forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the compiler will do for you. In case of GCC it will use a jump table.

Comment: By any chance, do you know a argument which would disable this feature? I'm using -O0 and it still optimizes it into the jump table. I would like to test and compare few things where it's enabled and when it's disabled. Just I do not know how forcefully disable this feature.

Comment: Oh I found a way to control it indirectly, by changing the threshold. `--param=case-values-threshold=999`

Answer (score 0):

c (and by extension c++) only switches on integer types, so hashing is not necessary. The compiler will typically use an idiom appropriate to the architecture you're compiling for. This could be indexed addressing (if a small range is used), jump tables, or something entirely different.

Comment: Hashing isn't necessary, but occasionally it's possible to optimise a bunch of integer cases using a perfect hash as the index into a jump table - basically take a set of non-consecutive numbers and map them to a consecutive space faster than you could traverse a binary decision tree. Whether that's an optimisation any compiler-writer can be bothered with is another matter...

Comment: @Steve: I'll take your word for it, but on the architectures that I have known enough assembly to even comment on (mostly pretty old these days) a jump table would uniformly be faster. Even a two level jump table to manage sparse  targets over a large integer range.

Comment: The one exception I could image would be a perfect hash for a set of binary flags. I.e. if all "case values" are powers of 2.

Comment: Or suppose the cases are sequential multiples of 147. I would strongly expect the perfect hash "divide by 147" (and check remainder is 0), followed by a jump table, to be faster than any generic switch. But I also wouldn't expect a compiler to come up with that. There are lots of situations where a perfect hash would be fast, the difficulty is finding the hashing function that does it. And in C, enumerated types don't quite do what you want, so a perfect hash on the cases does need a check to catch other values.

Answer (score 0):

A hash does not seem like an efficient way to implement a switch, because you will have extra cache misses due to the lookup.